# Travel Guide book for Asia with toddler/ young children?

Tags: children, guides, asia

We're planning to backpack a couple of month in Asia. Starting in Thailand and then going to Vietnam, maybe more places in the region. I'm looking for a travel guide, a Lonely Planet or Roughguide type of book especially on the topic of traveling with kids (ours is gonna be roughly 1 1/2 when we'll head off). I did find [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Travel-Children-Lonely-Planet-Guides/dp/0864427298#reader_0864427298) and [this one](http://www.roughguides.com/website/shop/products/Travel-with-Babies-and-Young-Children.aspx). Both are very general and cover only four pages for the whole region Asia! Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of information are you expecting to find in this guide that is not in the normal guidebooks?

Comment: I was thinking about: hotel/hostels that have a crib, are child friendly, things that are great to do with kids nearby, advice on food, and so on. In general everything that helps to avoid the greatest pitfalls of traveling with kids (imaging you stand in front of a hostel, it is getting dark and they won't give you a room).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not need a guide specifically for kids, as all recent editions of Lonely Planet guides include little "family friendly" icons next to all listings that are considered family friendly, which means:

> Indicates children are welcome and accommodated for through the
>   facilities available (eg has change rooms, an elevator, flexible
>   sleeping arrangements, children’s menus etc). Not used to indicate a
>   child might enjoy a place (eg a theme park) – that should be clear
>   from the review.

Most books also have a *Travelling with Children* chapter with various highlights (and pitfalls) for kids in that city/country.  And while this won't help in your specific case, for older kids (8+), there's also the [Not for Parents](http://shop.lonelyplanet.com/shopSearch?q=not%20for%20parents) series intended specifically for kids to read and use themselves.

And, as a traveling father of a 1.5-year-old myself, I'll heartily second Grzenio's recommendation to book accommodation in advance.  Kid-hostile restaurants etc you can always deal with somehow (take-away, one parent takes the kid for a walk while the other eats, etc), but conjuring a hotel room or crib out of thin air is a bit harder.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that such a publication exists (yet), unfortunately.

What I usually do is spend loads of time on-line before (and during) my travel with Kids on trip advisor, travel forums, google, etc. to figure out all the details myself. Often I would contact the hotel in advance to ask if they have appropriate facilities.

Also, especially when (a) arriving late (b) arriving in a big city (c) travelling in high season (d) travelling in Europe - I tend to book accommodation in advance. It is a pain, and strips the backpacking experience of this sense of freedom you get when travelling alone - but it is a substantially bigger pain to look for accommodation for hours with a small, hungry and tired child.

Comment: I was afraid that it is so. Just double-checking with the experts;-) The web indeed is a great source but, would still be great to have something like a guide book at hand while being on the road. Anyhow, thanks for posting.